# Converter numero para minuto e subtrair esses minutos de uma coluna que contenha data e hora R

Tags: r

Bom dia, possuo uma coluna (minutos1) que possui dados da quantidade de min (105,90,80)

Preciso transformar esses minutos em horas (HH:MM), após isso subtrair essas horas criadas de outra coluna inicio (DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM) que possui dados em  data e hora e minuto ("2018-06-01 12:00", "2018-06-01 11:00", "2018-06-01 15:20")

Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Entendo que agora ele esteja querendo o contrário. Nessa pergunta que você linkou, ele gostaria de transformar horas em minutos e, agora, ele quer transformar minutos em horas e depois fazer umas operações.

Comment: Luis recomendo que você, ao criar uma pergunta aqui no site, coloque o seu banco de dados, ou uma parte dele para que a gente possa te ajudar de forma mais fácil. Pesquise sobre o comando `dput` no `R`

Comment: Entendo o teu ponto de vista, mas uma pergunta não seria o inverso da outra? Imagino que o AP consiga interpretar o código fornecido no link que coloquei e realizar a operação inversa caso se tente. Veja que a pergunta sequer tem uma tentativa de solução.

Comment: @MarcusNunes você está coberto de razão. É mais fácil criar uma nova pergunta do que se debruçar em tentativas

Comment: Boa tarde pessoal, desculpa a demora em responder, 

O que acontece tenho uma coluna Tempototal = c("15/08/2018 06:00", "16/08/2018 10:35") 
solo = c("01:00", "02:00")

e inicio.de.uso que tem que ser  c("15/08/2018 05:00", "16/08/2018 08:35")

Por isso pedi a primeira pergunta, agora tenho que converter os minutos em horas, subtrair esses minutos da coluna tempototal, e criar uma nova coluna com o campo data e a hora dessa subtração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei um banco de dados com o exemplo das variáveis que você informou para facilitar.

```
dados <- data.frame(
  inicio = c("2018-06-01 12:00", "2018-06-01 11:00", "2018-06-01 15:20"),
  minuto1 = c(105, 90, 80) )
```

Utilizei o pacote `chron`

```
library(chron)

#criação da variável horas_inicias, extraindo essa informação de inicio
dados$horas_inicio <- as.character(substr(dados$inicio, 12, 16))
#acréscimo de segundos para utilizar a função times
dados$horas_inicio <- paste0(dados$horas_inicio, ":00")
#transformação da variável para tempo
dados$horas_inicio <- times(dados$horas_inicio)
#criação da variável horas, transformando minutos
dados$horas <- times((dados$minuto1%/%60 +  dados$minuto1%%60 /60)/24)
#cálculo da diferença de tempo entre as variáveis criadas
dados$diferença <- dados$horas_inicio - dados$horas
```

Comment: Rafael muito obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda.